# Pass argument values within sibling containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

My requirement is something like this:

Inside `docker1` I want to run a script:

```
python3 run script.py --path <remote_url>
```

When `--path` argument is passed to `script.py`, I want to launch `docker2` from `docker1` as a sibling container,
and pass the value of `--path` to `docker2`.

I am able to launch `docker2` from `docker1` as a sibling container, based on the presence of
`--path` argument, but how to pass on that value to `docker2`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could set the arguments as an environmental variable (in your dockerfile) and use docker-compose to launch both containers with that environment.

Comment: How exactly are you launching the second container?  If you were launching it in isolation, how would you pass that argument in?